# Linux - stuck on boot

Tags: linux

restarted machine but I'm stuck now on boot with errors in attach.

The os is an OL 7.5.

I tried to reinstall/reconfigure Grub with no success. Does LVM can be the cause ?

Please help !

Thanks.

[image: error image]

[image: error image 2]

Comment: I do not see any obvious reason for *running out of memory during boot* - consider telling grub to start a suitable rescue mode and activate services one by one to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Did you remove a disk from the system? Reconnect it.

Comment: I'm on VM and all the disks are attached

Answer (score 0):

I think of two issue.
[1] Either fstab having wrong entries(wrong entry or disk itself not exists now), so you are getting timeout.
[2] May be you are running systemd init script with fork type which is causing **failed to fork** issue
Could you please double check these 2 things? Above issue don't looks related to GRUB.